# How is this scrolling effect called and (how) can i disable this?

Tags: javascript, safari

so in safari, im able to scroll over the borders of a website.

[image]

When i release my finger, it "jumps" back. Does this effect have a name? Am I theoretically able to force my website to disable this (preferably without any JS)?

Comment: welcome to the world of "apple" it's actually patented by them. you cannot do anything about it but switching to android.

Answer (score 0):

This elastic behaviour entirely down to the user agent there is no way to affect this from within the window.